# Python microframework (Bottle, Flask) and socket.io

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to build an application with a websocket like functionality
I'm using python (will be deployed on heroku with gunicorn)

So far my search led me to Bottle. A replacement for my current microframework - Flask.
Bottle allows websocket functionality. http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/async.html

My question is: Could I use the javascript part of socket.io (or something similar) to connect to Bottle? If yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Socket.IO enables real-time web communications between a browser and a server. You need socketIO JS for the client side and gevent-socketio or gevent-websocket on the server side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to get started, take a look at the examples in here:

- https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/tree/master/examples

There's also a bottle example up here:

- https://github.com/reinbach/gevent-socketio-example/blob/master/app.py

You might want to start with the documentation at this address:

- https://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [flask-socket.io](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO), which would work with your current framework -- Flask. Aside from wrapping the lower-level functionality (gevent/SocketIO), it also adds some higher level functions such as rooms so you can group your users together.

Served me well on a previous project.